# Plot historical evolution of metric by user

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data from one year separated by months saved as factors in the format "MMM" (Meaning "JAN","FEB"...)
Each `User` has its calculated average of a metric by month. 
ie

```
User Month Metric
U1  JAN 0.55
U1  FEB 0.52
U1  MAR 0.40
U2  JAN 0.94
U2  FEB 0.06
U2  MAR 0.76
U3  JAN 0.07
U3  FEB 0.03
U3  MAR 0.17
```

How can i plot a line for each `user` (in the same graph) showing the monthly evolution of the `metric`? (Keep in mind `Month` is stored as factor)

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data, show your code! Eventually `matplot()` can do it for you after reshaping 'long' to 'wide'.

Comment: Are you looking for: `ggplot(df, aes(Month, Metric, color = User, group = User)) + geom_line()` ?

Comment: that is a good enough approach! The only problem is that the month in the X axis are not ordered

Comment: Then you have to change the ordering of the levels of your Month factor.

Answer (score 2):

**1) zoo** Assuming that the input is as provided reproducibly in the Note at the end of this answer, replace the months with month numbers, convert to a wide form zoo series with one column per user and plot. Add the month axis.  Both classic and ggplot2 graphics are shown.

```
library(zoo)

DF2 <- transform(DF, Month = match(Month, toupper(month.abb)))
z <- read.zoo(DF2, split = "User", index = "Month")

plot(z, screen = 1, xaxt = "n")
labs <- month.abb[time(z)]
axis(1, time(z), labs)
```

or

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z, facets = NULL) + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = time(z), labels = labs)
```

[image: screenshots]

**2) straight ggplot2**   Replace the factor levels with levels in the correct order.  The code here assumes that the data frame is sorted by User and Month, i.e. JAN comes before FEB, etc. in the data frame, but that the  factor levels of Month might not be set correctly.  If the factor levels are already set correctly then we can omit this part.  Finally plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

DF2 <- transform(DF, Month = factor(Month, levels = unique(Month)))
ggplot(DF2, aes(Month, Metric, group = User)) + geom_line()
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

The input used, in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "User Month Metric
U1  JAN 0.55
U1  FEB 0.52
U1  MAR 0.40
U2  JAN 0.94
U2  FEB 0.06
U2  MAR 0.76
U3  JAN 0.07
U3  FEB 0.03
U3  MAR 0.17"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```